# Capturing text selection event on mobile/touch devices

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile, dom-events

For my html application I want to do an action every time that some text is selected.

Right now I'm using the mouseup event to catch text selection like shown in the code below. But on mobile devices this does not work since mouseup is not fired after a selection. Which event can I use instead?

```
$("#container-around-text").on('mouseup', function() {
  // check if selection is empty
  // then do something
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe store a variable selectedText and run an interval every 100ms or so that checks to see if the current selected text is the same as that store in selectedText variable. If it is different, perform an action.

Comment: hm. Polling would probably work. But to me that seems pretty 'hackish' since I'm always executing code which may slow down the browser. I would rather prefer not using polling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `touchstart` and `touchend`, these are the events that `mousedown` and `mouseup` attempt to mimic.
Bind these events to your text element and trigger a function you want, something like:

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseup", selectableTextAreaMouseUp);
function selectableTextAreaMouseUp(event){
    var selectedText = window.getSelection();
    // do what you want
}
```